# Android Runtime permissions finish calling activity

Tags: android, back-stack, activity-stack, runtime-permissions

I recently came across this problem and almost pulled my hair out. Whenever my application ran for the first time - on Marshmallow (API 23) or above - my application would ask for a few run time permissions.

As soon as the native runtime permissions dialogue appeared, the actual activity behind would finish.

I will be answering the solution myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `android:noHistory` attribute of the calling activity's entry in `AndroidManifest.xml` is NOT set to `true`. By default, it is false. But in case you have set it to true, the above issue will be produced

Comment: Save my day! Thanks!